# Can I use my cell phone's internet connection as a VPN?

Tags: remote-control, vpn, ssh

I'm still learning about VPNs so forgive me if this sounds horribly mistaken, but if I understand it correctly a VPN is an encrypted internet connection between two computers that can also be used as proxy. My question is: supposing I am ON MY LAPTOP at a library/work/school and the WiFi has a filter that prevents access to some websites, in theory would I be able use the unfiltered 4G data connection from my Android tablet or phone to gain access to those sites remotely?

I know I could just tether the device and use the connection that way but I'm curious if it'd possible to use the data plan on the tablet that I leave at home (it has perfect 4G data service there) that way, should I ever need to use an encrypted connection to get around some web filters, I could always have that available to me. I currently don't have a home computer that I can leave running all day, otherwise I'd run something like Hamachi.

Thanks for reading and sorry if this is a noobish question!

Answer (score -1):

You can use VPN applications to access restricted websites on any android tablet/phone.
Here are a few of them 
[Flash VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flash.VPN_Free)
[Hot spot shield](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hotspotshield.android.vpn)

But i think you will not get exact 4G speeds while using VPN.

Answer (score -1):

Using the VPN that way would be redundant. 
Say you're at school and you would like to use an encrypted connection. Once you have established an encrypted connection it will pass most network filters. There would be no need for a proxy for encryptions sake. At least no need if you're just trying to by pass school filters... ;)